# PHP:Check duplicate values in all nested array

Tags: php

I would like to find out a duplicate value in the all nested arrays within an array.
At the moment my array is something like that.

```
Array $bigarray = Array (
    [431] => Array (
        [0] => orange 
        [1] => apple 
        [2] => pine
    ) 
    [440] => Array ( 
        [0] => orange 
        [1] => lilly 
    ) 
    [444] => Array (  
        [0] => orange 
        [1] => pine 
    ) 
)
```

I would like to extract only `orange` which is in all

```
arrays('431','440','444').
```

Woudl you give me some idea...?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php):

```
$intersected = null;
foreach ($bigarray as $arr) {
  $intersected = $intersected ? array_intersect($arr, $intersected) : $arr;
  if (!$intersected) {
    break; // no reason to continue
  }
}
print_r($intersected);

Array
(
  [0] => orange
)
```

Comment: thanks this is exactly what I wanted!! by the way i want to know how to delete the extracted items from all the arrays. i tried foreach ($clauses as $arr){..unset.} but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

```
$inAllChunks = call_user_func_array('array_intersect',(array_values($bigarray)));
var_dump($inAllChunks);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$output = null;

foreach ( $bigarray as $array ) {
  if ( is_null($output) ) {
    $output = $array;
    continue;
  }

  $output = array_intersect($output, $array);
  if ( empty($output) ) {
    break;
    // there are no common elements in the array
  }
}

var_dump$(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation.

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");  
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php